# Bootable usb with Ubuntu 22.04 iso gives a black screen

Tags: boot, usb

I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 on my hp zbook. I have done so before with 18.04 without issues. I have created the bootable usb with Rufus.
Whenever i plug in the usb and try to turn on my laptop it only shows a black screen, not even showing the HP logo and 'press Esc to ...' text. So i can not acces the boot menu to select booting from usb. When i turn on my laptop without the usb i do get to see the hp logo, i can access the bios/boot menu etc.

As far as i know all my bios/boot settings are according to the instructions, so idk what could cause this. I have tried different usb ports, recreating the bootable usb

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Comment: Of course you made a second USB boot device to verify the USB is not bad.

Comment: Or tried the flash drive on another computer?